# tengo un problema de compatibilidad con la gema de activerecord en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ya cambiado la version de las gemas para buscar una que sea compatible pero no e logrado encontrar la solucion todavia les agredeceria mucho si me pudieran ayudar con este problema, el problema se presenta al momento de ejecutar el bundle install, tambien intente actualizar usando bundle update

```
este es el error que me sale:
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord (~> 5.1, >= 5.1.7)

    rails (~> 6.0.1) was resolved to 6.0.2.rc1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.rc1)
```

---

este es mi gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.1'
# Use sqlserver as the database for Active Record
# gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.7'
# gem 'activerecord', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.15'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'tiny_tds', '>=2.1.0'

#dependencias
gem 'actioncable', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'actionmailbox', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
# gem 'actionmailer', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
# gem 'actionpack', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'actiontext', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'actionview', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'activejob', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
# gem 'activemodel', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
# gem 'activerecord', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'activestorage', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'activesupport', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
# gem 'bundler', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'
gem 'railties', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Tu problema es que tienes `gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.1'` en tu `Gemfile`, el cual es solo compatible con rails 5.1. En general no deberías definir en tu `Gemfile` las versiones de cada una de las gemas que son parte de rails, como `activerecord`, `actioncable`, `actionmailbox`, etc. Creo que deberías borrar todas esas dependencias (o explicar en tu pregunta del por qué las pusiste bajo esa etiqueta `#dependencias`) y solo dejar la definición de `gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.1'`

Comment: gracias el problema eran las versiones, lo de la etiqueta de dependencias es solo una referencias para mi para no perder donde comienzan, solo que a hora cuando ejecuta rails s me esta marcando este error con es con el metodo alias_method_chain.                                                      
`singleton class': undefined method `alias_method_chain' for #<Class:ActiveRecord::Base> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  alias_method

Comment: Si resolviste tu problema, agrega como respuesta cual fue tu solución. Respecto a lo otro, creo que deberías hacer una nueva pregunta, donde agregues más detalles de cual es tu problema. Saludos

Comment: ok gracias la verdad es que soy nuevo en la comunidad, resolvi el problema dejando de espificar la version de las gemas